# Get Managed MetaData full path of terms as IDs

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store

I want to ask if it is possible to get the current term's full path from term store as IDs.

Normally we get the full path like this

> "TermLabel;Term1Label;Term2Label"

But I want a return string as

> "TermID;Term1ID;Term2ID"

how can i get this ?